# Tcp .Send Doesn't work after using for the first time

Tags: c#, tcp

I am Using`Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message));` to send a message to the client, when i tried sending a second message it doesn't give any error so i think it send with no problem but it never reaches the client (127.0.0.1)

Code That Send

```
        public void SendMessage(Socket _Client, string Message)
    {
        foreach (Socket Client in Clients)
        {
            IPEndPoint TargetEndPoint = _Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            IPAddress TargetIp = TargetEndPoint.Address;
            int TargetPort = TargetEndPoint.Port;

            IPEndPoint ClientEndPoint = Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            IPAddress ClientIp = ClientEndPoint.Address;
            int ClientPort = ClientEndPoint.Port;

            if (TargetIp.ToString() == ClientIp.ToString() && TargetPort == ClientPort)
            {
                Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message));
                //Client.EndSend();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code That Receive

```
        private void RecivedCallBack(IAsyncResult Result)
    {
        //Create a int with the Buffer Size
        int BufferSize = _Socket.EndReceive(Result);
        //Create a new byte array with the Buffer Size
        byte[] Packet = new byte[BufferSize];
        //Copy Buffer to Packet
        Array.Copy(_Buffer, Packet, Packet.Length);

        //Handle Packet
        PacketHandler.Packet(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Packet));

        //Makes _Buffer a new byte
        _Buffer = new byte[1024];
        //Get Ready to recive data
        _Socket.BeginReceive(_Buffer, 0, _Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecivedCallBack, null);
    }
```

Code that Handle

```
        public static void Packet(string Message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Message);
        switch (Message)
        {
            case "StartChat":
                    _ChatForm Start = new _ChatForm();
                    Start.ShowDialog();
                break;
            case "StopChat":
                _ChatForm._Chat.EndChat();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think the second send didnt work?

Comment: it never reaches the client because every time a message reach the firs thing it does is print it

Comment: You need to include the full code of both the send and receving handlers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ok i did it

Comment: Yep, you forgot to do [Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)

Comment: I don't believe how many errors you have with the small number of lines of code.  1) you should open connection once before you enter for loop, 2) The send and receive should use the same connection.  You have two connections 3) You have a receive call back which is async.  The send must also use async.  Your send method is synchronous.

Comment: @jdweng `I don't believe how many errors you have with the small number of lines of code.` 

Please refrain from such comments as they help the OP in no way whatsoever and only serve your own ego, while harming his/hers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is stream based, so your client has no way to know when the message has ended. Either use UDP, implement a way to detect the end of messages (eg send a 4 byte message with the length of the real message, before sending the real message... and read on the client until the whole message has been received), or use a library. I like Hazel: https://github.com/DarkRiftNetworking/Hazel-Networking.

The great thing about Hazel is that it implements reliable UDP. So, if you need to have your "messages" arrive in the order in which they were sent, or if you need guaranteed delivery and receipt of such messages (such as what TCP provides), then you can do so with their reliable UDP implementation.

They will also implement Web Sockets at some point :) Good luck!

A client/server example from the [documentation](http://www.darkriftnetworking.com/Help.cshtml):

**Server**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Net;

 using Hazel;
 using Hazel.Tcp;

namespace HazelExample
{
class ServerExample
{
    static ConnectionListener listener;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new TcpConnectionListener(IPAddress.Any, 4296);

        listener.NewConnection += NewConnectionHandler;

        Console.WriteLine("Starting server!");

        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

        Console.ReadKey();

        listener.Close();
    }

    static void NewConnectionHandler(object sender, NewConnectionEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New connection from " + args.Connection.EndPoint.ToString();

        args.Connection.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

        args.Recycle();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, DataEventArgs args)
    {
        Connection connection = (Connection)sender;

        Console.WriteLine("Received (" + string.Join&lt;byte&gt;(", ", args.Bytes) + ") from " + connection.EndPoint.ToString());

        connection.SendBytes(args.Bytes, args.SendOption);

        args.Recycle();
    }
}
}
```

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Hazel;
using Hazel.Tcp;

namespace HazelExample
{
class ClientExample
{
    static Connection connection;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkEndPoint endPoint = new NetworkEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 4296);

        connection = new TcpConnection(endPoint);

        connection.DataReceived += DataReceived;

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting!");

        connection.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

        Console.ReadKey();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: or if you know that both ends are c# you can use BinaryWriter and BinaryReader. THis nicely frames the data for you

Comment: @pm100 Yep, but TBH, I prefer to not go that route... just so that I'm not tied to developing in C#.